# In order recursion in binary trees

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, inorder

Can someone please explain to me how recursion works in in Order traversal. here's my inOrder() method.

```
public void inOrder(BinaryNode p){
        if(p.left!=null){
            inOrder(p.left);
        }

        visit(p);

        if(p.right!=null){
            inOrder(p.right);
        }


    }
    public void visit(BinaryNode p){
        System.out.println(p.element);
    }

BinaryTree t=new BinaryTree();
        t.insert(5);
        t.insert(t.root,4);
        t.insert(t.root,6);
        t.insert(t.root,60);
        t.insert(t.root,25);
        t.insert(t.root,10);
        t.inOrder(t.root);
```

The method inOrder() prints the elements correctly,but I don't understand how it works.
When I call `t.inOrder(t.root);` since root has value 5 it would be similar to `inOrder(5);`
 and that has a left node so `if(p.left!=null){
                inOrder(p.left);
            }`

would get executed.There the  recursion call would be `inOrder(4);`
Since 4's left points to null, then `visit(4)` is the line that executed printing the value 4.
But then after that how does 5 get printed.Although at first when the method was called by `t.inOrder(t.root);` the local variable p was assigned with BinaryNode of value 5, now p is 4. Then after printing out 4, the next line that can get executed is

`if(p.right!=null){
                inOrder(p.right);
            }`
But since p.right now refers to right in BinaryNode with element 4 and 4's right is null, this also won't get executed.
Then how does the recursion is maintained?
How does it print out 5 and the rest of the nodes?

Comment: This is hard to explain without drawings ... Maybe find a video online ... But let me try. I think your problem is you're confusing values with nodes ; inOrder(root) is NOT quite the same as inOrder(5) ... Root is a node that has the 5 but also left and right

Comment: As to how it is implemented, there's usually a stack; when you call a function, the arguments get pushed into the stack, and also the place to return to; when returning, the results are put into the stack and the caller's address is taken out and we return to that place.

Comment: @okaram: I understand inOrder(root) is a BinaryNode taken as the argument.I wrote inOrder(5) just so that I can explain it easily

Comment: Ok, then let me try to explain ... When you call a function(recursive or not) the compiler generates code to push the arguments, and the current address ; so when you call inOrder(root) the compiler pushes root into the stack, and then the current address; when you get inside the function, you call inOrder(left), si tours he's that value, and the current address (now inside the function) ... This continues until left is null. At which time you go back to the last caller, and continue from there. BTW, you probable ought to be sending pointers ...

Comment: @okaram: So when the recursion finally reaches its base case then all the intermediate recursion calls are evaluated right?I still don't get the concept correctly though

Comment: sort of ... when the recursion reaches a base case, it goes back to the most recent call (takes values out of the stack, goes back to the last place), and continues from there ... if it was going to the left, it would print and then go right ... for tail recursion it unwinds all of them last, but the recursion is more complicated here.

Comment: I've setup a word doc trying to explain one case ... https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=84334A138AC1CCE0!5167&authkey=!AOPWWvAIdItz2a0&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: @okaram: Thank you very much for the time and effort put into answering the question.I'd have to look at it carefully and would do it when I get some free time

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to say.. It depend on your implementation..

I added implementation with in order traverse.. Hope that helps

```
class BinaryTreeSearch{
 public enum State{
 Visited, Unvisited,Visiting;

}
//this is the Node used in the tree
  static class Node{
    private int data;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    public Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
    public void setLeft(Node left){
        this.left = left;
    }
    public void setRight(Node right){
        this.right = right;
    }
    public Node getLeft(){
        return this.left;
    }       
    public Node getRight(){
        return this.right;
    }
    public int getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
    public boolean equals(Node n){
        if(this.data ==(int) n.getData()) return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    BinaryTreeSearch bts = new BinaryTreeSearch();
    bts.run();
}
//execute the test case
public void run(){
    Node root = new Node(10);
    insert(root,new Node(20));
    insert(root,new Node(5));
    insert(root,new Node(4));
    insert(root,new Node(5));
    insert(root,new Node(15));

    inOrderTraverse(root);
    System.out.println("\n" + binarySearch(root,new Node(10)));
}

// insert a node to the binary search tree
public void insert(Node root, Node n){
    if(root == null|| n == null) return;

    if(root.getData() > n.getData()){
        if(root.getLeft() == null){
            root.setLeft(n);
             System.out.println("Added node to left of "+root.getData()+" of value "+n.getData());           
        }else{
            insert(root.getLeft(),n);
        }

    }else if(root.getData() < n.getData()){
        if(root.getRight() == null){
            root.setRight(n);
            System.out.println("Added node to Right of "+root.getData()+" of value "+n.getData());     
        }else{
            insert(root.getRight(),n);
        }

    }
}
//in-order Traversal
public void inOrderTraverse(Node root){
    if(root != null){
        inOrderTraverse(root.getLeft());
        System.out.print("  "+root.getData());
        inOrderTraverse(root.getRight());
    }

}
//binary search
public boolean binarySearch(Node root,Node n){
    if(root == null || n == null) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("  Testing out "+root.getData()+" for value "+n.getData());
    if(root.getData() > n.getData()){
       return  binarySearch(root.getLeft(),n);
    }else if(root.getData() < n.getData()){
       return  binarySearch(root.getRight(),n);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've explained the best i could without images.
do print(i) means printing i
and do inorder(i) means inorder(i) is expanded to inorder(left of i) > print (i) > inorder(right of i)

inorder(5) called

todo: inorder(4) > print 5 > inorder(6)

do inorder(4)

todo: inorder(left of 4)=nothing > print(4) > inorder(right of 4)=nothing > print(5)

> inorder 6

do print 4

do print 5

do inorder 6

todo: inorder(left of 6)=nothing > print 6 > inorder(60)

do print 6

do inorder 60

todo: inorder(25) > print 60 > inorder(right of 60)=nothing

do inorder 25

todo: inorder(10) > print 25 > inorder(right of 25)=nothing > print 60

do inorder 10

todo: inorder(left of 10)=nothing > print 10 >inorder(right of 10)=nothing >print 25>print 60

do print 10

do print 25

do print 60

So if you see the order of printing its 4 5 6 10 25 60