# printing binary search tree inorder recursively

Tags: java

I have the code for printing a the contents of a binary search tree in-order (ascending) using recursion. I understand that the helper method calls on the recursive method with root as the beginning node value. But I don't understand how the recursive code works conceptually. Could anyone explain?

```
//ascend method that prints values in the tree in ascending order
//recursive method below
public void printAscending() {
    printAscending(root);
}
private void printAscending(Node node) {
    if(node != null) {
        printAscending(node.left);   
        System.out.println(node.data);
        printAscending(node.right);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852798/in-order-recursion-in-binary-trees

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek please avoid meaningless edits in the future. Editing the post for a single space is not worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following (trivial) tree:

```
1
```

You'd be calling the function on the one (the root) and it is obvious to see that the result is `1`.

Now consider the following (slightly larger) tree:

```
 2
1
```

The root is now `2` and the output (manually traced by hand) gives `1 2`. *(spaces added for clarity)*

Similar manual tracing on the following gives us `1 2 3`:

```
 2
1 3
```

So we can now see that for small testcases, it seems to work fine.

Let's try proving it for larger testcases.

For any null node (i.e. if we are at a non-existant tree/subtree) we just exit.

For any non-null node, the `printAscending(node.left)` line is called first. This line MUST finish execution before anything else runs. This calls the `printAscending()` function using `node.left` as parameter which is equivalent to just looking at the left subtree of the current node, finishing the work there and then continuing the code. We can keep going down the left until we reach a null node. At this point of time, it moves back upwards, resuming from where it had stopped off. It runs `System.out.println(node.data)` which gives the output of a single node and then runs `printAscending(node.right)`. This causes it to enter the right subtree of the current node. Note that in this subtree, it runs the complete code (i.e. runs the left, center and then right parts). Once it is done running through the right subtree, it backs out of the subtree and the current node. This makes the node just above it (the parent) move on to the next part of the code.

If you follow a similar working, you'll see that the whole left subtree of the root is processed first, then the root is printed and then whole right subtree is processed.

Comment: I think the thing about recursive functions is that you either can see how they work or you can't. Worked examples are a good idea. To find out more about recursion, please re-read this comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// public entry point, reuses the recursive function
public void printAscending() {
    printAscending(root);
}

// print this node and all of its descendants
private void printAscending(Node node) {
    // is there actually a node here
    // or was this called from a node with no children
    if(node != null) {
        // print everything that's earlier than this node
        printAscending(node.left);   

        // print this node's value
        System.out.println(node.data);

        // print everything that's afterthan this node
        printAscending(node.right);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void printInOrder() {
        if (left != null) {
            left.printInOrder();
        }
        System.out.println(data);
        if (right != null) {
            right.printInOrder();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is better to explain the scenario then explain why your answer works.